# Update value in struct type column in java spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I want capability to update value in nested dataset. For this I have a created as nested Dataset in Spark. It has below schema structure:-

```
root

 |-- field_a: string (nullable = false)

 |-- field_b: struct (nullable = true)

 |    |-- field_d: struct(nullable = false)
          |-- field_not_to_update: string(nullable = true)

 |        |-- field_to_update: string(nullable = false)
 |   field_c: string (nullable = false)
```

Now I wanted to update value in `field_to_update` in the dataset. I have tried

```
aFooData.withColumn("field_b.field_d.field_to_update", lit("updated_val")
```

Also tried,

```
aFooData.foreach(new ClassWithForEachFunction());
```

where `ClassWithForEachFunction implements ForEachFunction<Row>` and has method `public void call(Row aRow)` to update field_to_update attribute. Tried same with lamda as well but it was throwing Task not serializable exception so has to go for long process.

None of them are fruitful so far and I am getting same Dataset with foreach and new column with name  `field_b.field_d.field_to_update` in second case. Any other suggestions for same?

Answer (score 1):

Please check below code.

- Extract the fields from struct
- Update the required filed.
- Reconstruct the struct back.

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-------+--------------+
|field_a|field_b       |
+-------+--------------+
|parentA|[srinivas, 20]|
|parentB|[ravi, 30]    |
+-------+--------------+


scala> df.printSchema
root
 |-- field_a: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field_b: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field_to_update: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- field_not_to_update: integer (nullable = true)


scala> df.select("field_a","field_b.field_to_update","field_b.field_not_to_update").withColumn("field_to_update",lit("updated_val")).select(col("field_a"),struct(col("field_to_update"),col("field_not_to_update")).as("field_b")).show(false)
+-------+-----------------+
|field_a|field_b          |
+-------+-----------------+
|parentA|[updated_val, 20]|
|parentB|[updated_val, 30]|
+-------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for this but I will need to do it Java.

Comment: If you could change it to scala, you could use spark optics to make this changes easier https://github.com/hablapps/sparkOptics

Comment: @Yashu, Almost same syntax for java & scala. Let me know if it is not working .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to reconstruct the whole schema, you can do it in a single instance with the following sentence.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{lit, struct}

df.select(
  df("field_a"), // keep the fields that don't change
  struct( // the field at first level must be reconstructed
     lit("updated_value") as "field_to_update", // transform or set the new elements
     df("fb.field_not_to_update") as "field_not_to_update" // keep the unchanged sub elements and keep the last name
  ) as "field_b", // and we have to keep the name
  df("field_c")
)
```

The syntax will be the same in java

Answer (score 0):

A more "Java-like" approach would be to convert the dataframe into a (typed) dataset and then use a [map](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#map-org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction-org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder-) call to change the data. From a Java perspective the code is easy to handle. But the downside is that you would need three [Java bean classes](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/spec-136004.html) for the given schema.

```java
Dataset<Bean1> ds = df.as(Encoders.bean(Bean1.class));

Dataset<Bean1> updatedDs = ds.map((MapFunction<Bean1, Bean1>) row -> {
    row.getField_b().getField_d().setField_to_update("updated");
    return row;
}, Encoders.bean(Bean1.class));
```

with the three Bean classes

```java
public static class Bean1 implements Serializable {
    private String field_a;
    private Bean2 field_b;
    private String field_c;

    //getters and setters
}

public static class Bean2 implements Serializable {
    private Bean3 field_d;

    //getter and setter
}

public static class Bean3 implements Serializable {
    private String field_not_to_update;
    private String field_to_update;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method [withField](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Column.html#withField-java.lang.String-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-) was introduced in Spark 3.1.1. As per the documentation: -

> An expression that adds/replaces field in StructType by name.

The following code snippet (in scala) shows this: -

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType, StructField, StringType}
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions

val structSchema = new StructType()
.add(new StructField("field_a", StringType, true))
.add(new StructField("field_b", 
new StructType().add(new StructField("field_not_to_update", StringType, true))
.add(new StructField("field_to_update", StringType, true)), 
true))
.add(new StructField("field_c", StringType, true))

val df = Seq("""{"field_a": "some-value-a", "field_b": {"field_not_to_update": "field_not_to_update_b", "field_to_update": "field_to_update_b"}, "field_c": "some-value-c"}""").toDF
val processedDf = df.withColumn(
          "processed_payload",
          functions.from_json(functions.col("value"), structSchema)
        )
val finalDf = processedDf.select("processed_payload.*")
println("Input dataframe: ")
finalDf.show(truncate=false)
val updatedDf = finalDf.withColumn("field_b", functions.col("field_b").withField("field_to_update", functions.lit("UPDATED_VALUE")))
println("Updated dataframe: ")
updatedDf.show(truncate=false)
```

The output of the above code snippet is as follows: -

```
Input dataframe: 
+------------+------------------------------------------+------------+
|field_a     |field_b                                   |field_c     |
+------------+------------------------------------------+------------+
|some-value-a|{field_not_to_update_b, field_to_update_b}|some-value-c|
+------------+------------------------------------------+------------+

Updated dataframe: 
+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
|field_a     |field_b                               |field_c     |
+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
|some-value-a|{field_not_to_update_b, UPDATED_VALUE}|some-value-c|
+------------+--------------------------------------+------------+
```